# TypeScript error when running Protractor test

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor

I have a small suite of Protractor tests. In with the tests, I have some page object classes that extend from a common base class. In my protractor config, I have:

```
specs: [
  './showcase/e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
]
```

If I run Protractor with this config, all the tests run. But, if I try to run a single test, I run into an error.

I'm trying to run a specific test with this command:

```
protractor --specs showcase/e2e/app/components/dropdown/dropdown.e2e-spec.ts
```

But then I get an error:

```
Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
showcase/e2e/shared/components/dropdown/dropdown.po.ts (3,32): Property 'setPrototypeOf' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. (2339)
```

Here is the contents of `dropdown.po.ts`:

```
import { ExamplePage } from '../example.po';

export const COMPONENT_ID = 'dropdown';

export class DropdownPage extends ExamplePage {
  navigateTo() {
    this.navigateToComponentPage('dropdown');
  }
}
```

There's got to be something I'm missing. Any idea why I get this error when I try to run a single test case, but no error when I run everything? I'm stumped.

Comment: It looks like you are using ecma6 when running the entire suite, but when you are running a single test, its target is not what you intend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the necessary fix.

In this case, I needed to add the following to `tsconfig.json`:

```
"lib": [
  "es2016",
  "dom"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to specify protractor conf in command line:

```
protractor --specs showcase/e2e/app/components/dropdown/dropdown.e2e-spec.ts
```

Correct one should be like:

```
protractor conf.js --specs showcase/e2e/app/components/dropdown/dropdown.e2e-spec.ts
```

Comment: I just tried that, specifying my config file, unfortunately I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `*.js` files instead of direct `*.ts`. Please use `tsc` for compiling your typescript code to javascript before running tests.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. When I run all the tests together (which are all written in TypeScript), I don't get the error.